# SelectKBest(mutual_info_regression) for classification

Tags: python, feature-selection

I am new to feature selection and am not sure whether I understood how to use feature selection for sentiment analysis. Does it make sense to try out SelectKBest(f_classif), SelectKBest(f_regression), SelectKBest(mutuial_info_classif) and SelectKBest(f_info_regression) for a classification problem? I would have thought it does not, only SelectKBest with f_classif and mutual_info_classif.

Answer (score 0):

**f_classif**

```
ANOVA F-value between label/feature for classification tasks.
```

**mutual_info_classif**

```
Mutual information for a discrete target.
```

**f_regression**

```
F-value between label/feature for regression tasks.
```

**mutual_info_regression**

```
Mutual information for a continuous target.
```

You have a discrete target, so no regression here. However, I would not use F-test based type of feature selection for large data sets, because it is based on statistical tests, and for large data sets any difference can become statistically significant and the selection peformance is almost none. (But as part of the task, you definitely can compare them.)

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. What kind of feature selection would make sense for sentiment analysis then?

Comment: Is it not possible to use it, if your classes can be seen as continuous when it is a classification for classes from 1 to 5?

Comment: Your classes are discrete, class 1, 2, 3, etc. However, the probability associated to each class is continuous. Btw, check this out: http://ml-ml.herokuapp.com/.